# Pmap throws recycling error after calling filter on dataset and first entry of list of function arguments

Tags: r, purrr

I want to filter and afterwars mutate a dataframe based on serveral conditions. All these conditional vectors have the same length. Still pmap throws an recycling error. Of course the dataset here is just an example. Executing the code below throws the following error :

> Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
> x Can't recycle `..1` (size 7679) to match `..2` (size 11).
> i Input `..1` is `.$country == country_code`.

Do I use pmap wrong here?

```
 f_ycomp <- function(dataset, country_code, yrbirth, crit_year, ycomp, ycomp_else){
      dataset_new <- dataset %>%
        filter(.$country == country_code) %>%
        mutate(ycomp = ifelse(.$yrbirth >=crit_year, ycomp,ycomp_else))
      return(dataset_new$ycomp)
    }  


 dataset <- tibble(country = floor(runif(7679,1,50)),ybirth = floor(runif(7679,1900,1970)))
    
    cohort_yr_mean_ger <- floor(mean(c(1941, 1934, 1947, 1943, 1953, 1953, 1953, 1953, 1955, 1949)))
    
    crit_year <- c(1947,1969,1957,1953,cohort_yr_mean_ger,1958,1958,1949,1959,1947,1947)
    ycomp <- c(9,12,9,10,9,9,9,9,10,8,9)
    ycomp_else <- c(8,8,7,8,8,6,8,5,9,6,8)
    country_filter <- c(11,23,18,17,12,19,30,16,14,13,15)

    ycomp <- pmap(list(country_filter,crit_year,ycomp,ycomp_else),
                      ~f_ycomp(dataset = dataset, country_code = country_filter, crit_year = crit_year, ycomp = ycomp, ycomp_else = ycomp_else))%>%
          unlist())
```

Comment: I think the dollar sign notation in `mutate()` is causing that particular error, although I think something else may be wrong, as well.

Comment: Controlled for that. It looks more like pmap tries to throw in the whole vector instead of element by element in each iteration.

Comment: `country_code = country_filter`, ... passes the whole vector to your fun. Instead use `country_code = ..1` to refer to the first argument in your list, `..2` for the second and so on. See `?pmap`

Comment: Like this?
`f_ycomp <- function(dataset, country_code, crit_year, ycomp, ycomp_else){
  dataset_new <- dataset %>%
    filter(.$country == ..1) %>%
    mutate(ycomp = ifelse(.$yrbirth >=..2, ..3,..4))
  return(dataset_new$ycomp)
}`

This throws me :
Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x ..1 used in an incorrect context, no ... to look in
i Input `..1` is `.$country == ..1`.

Comment: @mugdi. No. (: Not in the function but in teh `pmap`: `pmap(list(country_filter,crit_year,ycomp,ycomp_else), ~f_ycomp(dataset = dataset, country_code = ..1, crit_year = ..2, ....`